# EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read error in all Vite projects on Ubuntu 23

Tags: vue.js, ubuntu, vite, nvm

I'm experiencing an issue with all of my Vite projects on my Ubuntu 23 machine. Whenever I try to start any Vite project, I get the following error:

`error when starting dev server: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read at Object.readSync (node:fs:738:3) at tryReadSync (node:fs:438:20) at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:484:19) at hasWorkspacePackageJSON (file:///home/sergio/Documents/repositories/project/project-dashboard/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-a178814b.js:13664:37) ...`

I've already checked the following:

- File permissions are 777.
- Project dependencies are correct.
- Node.js version is correct (using NVM).

I'm wondering if this could be a compatibility issue between Vite and Ubuntu 23, as I haven't found any specific information about this. Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a solution?

Thanks!